# Is there any way to access java swing help from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

is there any way to have Java Swing help/docs appear in Eclipse when floating over a Swing item.   It would save a lot of time bringing up a Google search.

Comment: What do you mean with "Java Swing help/ docs"? The Javadoc? The tutorial?

Comment: Do you want to integrate (Swing's) JavaHelp into your Eclipse/SWT application?

Comment: Download and install a JDK (instead of a JRE). JDK come with their source code and are automatically bound to the corresponding JRE by Eclipse. JavaDoc will then automatically appear and you can even navigate the source code (using `F3` or `CTRL+Click`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First download the corresponding docs for your jre, I have 7 so I would get [this one](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java-se-7-doc-download-435117.html). *(You can alternatively use the online method but this way is faster and you can use it offline)*

Open Eclipse and go to *Window* > *Preferences* > *Java* > *Installed JREs*. You can then select the jre you are using and click *edit*.

[image]

Select all the `.jar` items from JRE system libraries then click *Javadoc Location...*, Tick *Javadoc in archive* and then locate the `.zip` you downloaded, set it to Archive path and set the *Path within archive* textbox to `docs/api`.

[image]

You can then check to see if this is set up properly by clicking *Validate*. It should print a similar message like the one above. *(Location is likely valid..)*

Hover over a keyword and it should popup the docs, you can press <kbd>F2</kbd> to 'focus' on the information. You can also use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to open it in a new tab.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - absolutely text book guidance, much appreciated - Ron